# Android: How to reference library drawable in app manifest

Tags: android, resources, manifest, drawable

I have a free android app that I want to now distribute as free (with ads) and paid (without ads), so the only difference would be in a few of the layout files, where I just remove the ads in the paid version.

I tried moving all of my code from my existing free app to a new project which I set up as a library project, and I'm referencing the library project from the app project. In the manifest file.

What I want to do is completely contain the free app within this library project, and create two new app projects that reference the library, and change the layout file for the paid app, removing the ads.

I'm working on the paid app version and can't figure out how to reference the drawable for the app icon in the manifest file.

Am I going about this all wrong? Help is much appreciated.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

My knowledge is from reading similar conversations not from experience, but AFAIK any resources can NOT be referenced if they are contained inside the library from the app project.

Comment: My recent experience suggests otherwise: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6334724/636571