# How to reference an icon from a Library Project in Application's AndroidManifest.xml

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-library, library-project

I am trying to use the same application icon for all applications derived from a Library Project.

I thought that it would be as simple as implementing the advice provided [in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6241429/how-to-reference-a-drawable-from-a-library-project-into-a-main-projects-layout-i/6241484#6241484), but unfortunately it doesn't work.

What I did is add to the `<manifest>` tag in the application's `AndroidManifest.xml` the following line:

```
xmlns:mylib="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.example.baseapp"
```

And a few lines down the same `AndroidManifest.xml` file, change the typical `@drawable/icon` to:

```
   <application android:icon="@mylib:drawable/icon">
```

But it doesn't work!

Instead, Eclipse tells me that:

> error: Error: No resource found that
>   matches the given name (at 'icon' with
>   value '@omlib:drawable/icon').

Apparently, referencing drawables from a layout XML and the manifest XML are not the same.

How do I reference an icon from a Library Project in Application's AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: Did you try with drawable/icon only ? I don't know about your setup but it works for me.

Comment: @Snicolas `@drawable/icon` works but it requires copying the icon's PNG file to each and every application project that uses my Library Project. That is not what I want. I want to have the icon PNG file exist only once (in the Library Project) and reference it from all other (numerous) applications using it. Suggestion?

Comment: @Snicolas I am taking what I wrote above back! I just re-tried @drawable/icon but this time **with all icon.png files deleted from application's res subfolders** and it works! Phew... this is so tricky (with no apparent consistency or methodology). Please post your comment as an answer so that I can accept it. +1 in the meanwhile. :)

Comment: Does this work for other drawables as well, and just not XML resources?  I've tried the same with XML resources, but with no luck.  It's a pain having to copy and paste identical resources so much each time I make a change...

Comment: @areyling For other drawables see the link I mentioned when I first posted my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6241429/how-to-reference-a-drawable-from-a-library-project-into-a-main-projects-layout-i/6241484#6241484 The keyword appears to be **layout** XML.

Comment: Thanks for the response, @an00b .  I'm still not able to get that to work though...wondering if it might be the way I have the project structured.

Comment: For anyone else that struggled with this the way I did, there's a specific way to specify that an Android project is a library. I was trying to follow the help here without having done this; I only had the library listed as a Java dependency. Article here: http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/projects-eclipse.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Did you try with drawable/icon only ? I don't know about your setup but it works for me.

Perhaps after a good project and librairy clean up...

Comment: Your tip still holds true... even on the latest SDK R16... But another important tip must be added: When all fails, **exit Eclipse**, then start it again. It's sad to see how a remarkable productivity tool like Eclipse needs to resort to those kind of tricks, formerly attributed to Microsoft's operating systems...

Answer (score 6):

For people still reading this:
I believe this was fixed since SDK17.

you should write the following:

```
xmlns:mylib="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

This should enable you to reference resources from library projects as well.

Comment: For future reference, This is more of a comment than an answer.  :)

Comment: Don't agree. If you see the mess in the comment section below the OP's question i think it deserves to be an answer. :)